pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError in AKS cluster
We are using mcr.microsoft.com/azurelinux/base/python:3.12.3-4-azl3.0.20241101-amd64 as our base image to build python based application . when we are running our application built image in AKS , its failing to connect to azure cosmos db with error as below. We checked the connectivity from AKS container to the cosmosmongo db and there is no connection error.
When we built the application base image from docker hub python:3.12, the application is getting connected to the same mongo instance?
So here the problem is with this azurelinux base image or pymongo driver(pymongo==4.8.0) used in this base image?
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pymongo/synchronous/topology.py", line 333, in _select_servers_loop

    raise ServerSelectionTimeoutError(

pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError: mymongo.mongo.cosmos.azure.com:10255: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1000) (configured timeouts: socketTimeoutMS: 20000.0ms, connectTimeoutMS: 20000.0ms), Timeout: 30s, Topology Description: <TopologyDescription id: xxxxxxx, topology_type: ReplicaSetNoPrimary, servers: [<ServerDescription ('mymongo.mongo.cosmos.azure.com', 10255) server_type: Unknown, rtt: None, error=AutoReconnect('mymongo.mongo.cosmos.azure.com:10255: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1000) (configured timeouts: socketTimeoutMS: 20000.0ms, connectTimeoutMS: 20000.0ms)')>]>

